# does wrapper function execute at the same speed as bare function in php?

Tags: php

I wonder if wrapper function in php executes at the same speed as bare function. Is php engine optimized to detect these cases? Where can I read more about it?

I tried following, and it seems to return generally the same numbers both for `test` and `test_wrapper`

```
<?php

function test() {
return 1;
}

function test_wrapper() {
return test();
}

$time_start = microtime(true);

test_wrapper();

$time_end = microtime(true);

$execution_time = ($time_end - $time_start) / 60;

echo '<b>Total Execution Time:</b> '.$execution_time.' Mins';
```

Comment: those are far too short to determine anything. Try a loop that iterates 1000 times, and have far more complicated functions. If 1000 still returns the same, try 10000. But even that isn't accurate because the functions are I believe basically cached by php so there's optimizations happening in the loop. Loop 1 tests 1000 of the unwrapped function, loop 2 tests 1000 of the wrapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested this code and came to the conclusion there is not much difference.

```
$b = new \Benchmark(10000000, 1);

function test() {
  return 1;
}

function test_wrapper() {
  return test();
}

$b->register('test', function(){
  test();
});

$b->register('test_wrapper', function(){
  test_wrapper();
});

print_r($b->start());
```

Using my own [library](https://github.com/Xorifelse/php-benchmark-closure) these are the results:

```
Array
(
    [stats] => Array
        (
            [phpversion] => 7.1.2
            [itterations] => 20000000
            [duration] => 5.7083499431
            [fastest] => test
            [slowest] => test_wrapper
        )

    [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => test
                    [time] => 2.7408945560
                    [average] => 0.0000002741
                    [speed] => 7.63%
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => test_wrapper
                    [time] => 2.9674553871
                    [average] => 0.0000002967
                    [speed] => 0.00%
                )

        )

)
```